# loop inside an array to add dynamic data, in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to create an array inside an array by using a foreach loop, I have a sample out come and the problem is I can not produce the exact out come as the sample - here's my code:

```
$json = '{"id":"118","item_key":"m6jgm","name":"Bright Madire","ip":"192.168.92.81","meta":{"2b9ta":"Bright","qy6sa":"Madire","k9ngs":"Bright Madire","y69z6":"bmadire@vayaafrica.com","58nj0":"0774222497","q78bq":"IS","culq4":"Software Engineer","tqe5r":"IT and Electronics","procured_items":{"form":"11","i116":{"procured_item_name":"Macbook Pro","procured_item_quantity":"1","gmy78":"","wki9u":"","procured_item_description":"- 500GB SDD\r\n- 16GB Unified\r\n- M2 Chip Processor\r\n- 15\" Screen","arpya":""},"i117":{"procured_item_name":"Lenobo ThinkPad","procured_item_quantity":"2","gmy78":"","wki9u":"","procured_item_description":"- 500GB SDD\r\n- 16GB Unified\r\n- Core i7 Processor\r\n- 15\" Screen","arpya":""}},"procured_item_name":["Macbook Pro","Lenobo ThinkPad"],"procured_item_quantity":["1","2"],"gmy78":["",""],"wki9u":["",""],"procured_item_description":["- 500GB SDD\r\n- 16GB Unified\r\n- M2 Chip Processor\r\n- 15\" Screen","- 500GB SDD\r\n- 16GB Unified\r\n- Core i7 Processor\r\n- 15\" Screen"],"arpya":["",""],"zzrfl":"","1g8ya":"","6cm1d":"RFQ","qcl2b":"No","xx48b":"2023-07-27","zsii":"16:40","request_status":"Send To Suppliers","qaolg":"","sromp":"","department_approval":"Approve","tvghy":"","finance_approval":"Approve","w2iyy":"","2iyii":"","2iyii-value":"8","fsu1s":"","nh3tu":"3"},"form_id":"10","post_id":"0","user_id":"8","parent_item_id":"0","is_draft":"0","updated_by":"10","created_at":"2023-07-27 14:24:42","updated_at":"2023-07-27 14:37:10"}';

$entryArray = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $procuredItems = $entryArray['meta']['procured_items'];

    $first_field = 320;
    $second_field = 323;
    $third_field = 322;

    $ids = "0";
    $rows = "";
    $i = 1;
    $bigArray = array();
    
        $values[ 'value' ] = array(
          'form' => '10',
          'row_ids' => array( '0, 1' ),
        );
        
        
foreach($procuredItems as $key=>$value) {
  if ($key != "form"){
    
    // defining the dynamic values
    $title = $value['procured_item_name'];
    $quantity = $value['procured_item_quantity'];
    $desc = $value['procured_item_description'];

    // inserting the dynamic arrays into the main array
    $values[ 'value' ][] = array(
    $i-1 => array( 0 => '', $first_field => $value['procured_item_name'], $second_field => $value['procured_item_quantity'], $third_field => $value['procured_item_description'] ),
    );
    
    $i += 1;
  }
}

//this print my trial code output
var_dump( $values[ 'value' ] );
echo '</br>';
echo '</br>';
echo '</br>';

// Sample array structure
     $values[ 'value' ] = array(
       'form' => '10',
       'row_ids' => array( 0, 1 ),
          
        0 => array( 0 => '', $first_field => 'Macbook Pro', $second_field => '1', $third_field => '- 500GB SDD - 16GB Unified - M2 Chip Processor - 15" Screen' ),
        1 => array( 0 => '', $first_field => 'Lenobo ThinkPad', $second_field => '2', $third_field => '- 500GB SDD - 16GB Unified - Core i7 Processor - 15" Screen' ),
     );

// this print supposed sample output
var_dump( $values[ 'value' ] );
```

The correct printed array should be like this, the expected output below:

array(4) { ["form"]=> string(2) "10" ["row_ids"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) } [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [320]=> string(11) "Macbook Pro" [323]=> string(1) "1" [322]=> string(59) "- 500GB SDD - 16GB Unified - M2 Chip Processor - 15" Screen" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [320]=> string(15) "Lenobo ThinkPad" [323]=> string(1) "2" [322]=> string(59) "- 500GB SDD - 16GB Unified - Core i7 Processor - 15" Screen" } }

Unfortunalely my array is different because the moment I am trying to add those dynamic data, it adds another layer of an array. this is my output:

array(4) { ["form"]=> string(2) "10" ["row_ids"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "0, 1" } [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [320]=> string(11) "Macbook Pro" [323]=> string(1) "1" [322]=> string(62) "- 500GB SDD - 16GB Unified - M2 Chip Processor - 15" Screen" } } [1]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [320]=> string(15) "Lenobo ThinkPad" [323]=> string(1) "2" [322]=> string(62) "- 500GB SDD - 16GB Unified - Core i7 Processor - 15" Screen" } } }

I need help on producing the expected array.

Comment: Why would 'row_ids' in you sample result array be an array of one string [ '0, 1' ], and not an array of ints [ 0, 1 ] or strings [ '0', '1' ] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revise the following line

```
    // inserting the dynamic arrays into the main array
    $values[ 'value' ][] = array(
    $i-1 => array( 0 => '', $first_field => $value['procured_item_name'], $second_field => $value['procured_item_quantity'], $third_field => $value['procured_item_description'] ),
    );
```

to my version,

```
    // inserting the dynamic arrays into the main array
    $values[ 'value' ][$i-1] = array( 0 => '', $first_field => $value['procured_item_name'], $second_field => $value['procured_item_quantity'], $third_field => $value['procured_item_description'] );
```

Second, please formatting expected output, also using `print_r()` with `<pre>` more easier to read.

```
    print("<pre>");
    print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is too much complexity in your coding attempt.

If I am correctly understanding that `form` comes from `$entryArray['meta']['procured_items']['form']`, `row_ids` is a delimited string populated from the number of procured items, and you are pushing subsets of data into the result array, then the following should suffice.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JlCZA))

```
$result = [
    'form' => $entryArray['meta']['procured_items']['form'],
    'row_ids' => [''],
];
$i = 0;
foreach ($entryArray['meta']['procured_items'] as $k => $procuredItem) {
    if ($k === 'form') {
        continue;
    }
    $result['row_ids'][0] .= (strlen($result['row_ids'][0]) ? ', ' : '') . $i++;
    $result[] = [
        0 => '',
        320 => $procuredItem['procured_item_name'],
        323 => $procuredItem['procured_item_quantity'],
        322 => $procuredItem['procured_item_description'],
    ];
}
var_export($result);
```

Of course, you can use variables `$first_field`, `$second_field`, and `third_field` if there is some benefit in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = array_filter(
  $entryArray['meta']['procured_items'],
  fn($key) => $key !== 'form',
  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

$result = [
  'form'    => $entryArray['meta']['procured_items']['form'],
  'row_ids' => [ implode(', ', range(0, count($items) - 1)) ],
  ...array_map(
    fn($item) => [
      0   => '',
      320 => $item['procured_item_name'],
      323 => $item['procured_item_quantity'],
      322 => $item['procured_item_description'],
    ],
    array_values($items)
  )
];
```